# Use SqlDataAdapter and DataTable to get and update on SQL server with PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, datatable, sqldataadapter

I am trying to use PowerShell to get a `System.Data.DataTable` from an SQL server, edit the data, and update it back to the SQL server but I cannot get it to work. The below code runs/executes but the data is not changed.

```
$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=server,1234; Database=dingo; Trusted_Connection=True;")
$sqlConnection.open()

$sqlCommand = $sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.test"

$dt = new-object System.Data.DataTable
$adapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($sqlCommand)

$adapter.Fill($dt)

# edit the rows
$dt.Rows[0].BeginEdit()
$dt.Rows[0]["a"] = "nacho"
$dt.Rows[0].AcceptChanges()

# command builder
$cb = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder($adapter)

$adapter.UpdateCommand = $cb.GetUpdateCommand()


$adapter.Update($dt)

$sqlConnection.Close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not call [`AcceptChange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.acceptchanges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on the row, instead you need to call [`EndEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.endedit(v=vs.110).aspx).

When call `AcceptChanges`, it ends edit but marks the row as `Unchanged`, so it will not be processed by the `DataAdapter` since it's marked as unchanged.

> When invoking `AcceptChanges`, the `EndEdit` method is implicitly called
>   to end any edits. If the `RowState` of the row was `Added` or `Modified`,
>   the `RowState` becomes `Unchanged`. If the `RowState` was `Deleted`, the row
>   is removed.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!